# Get a list of files that contain an xml attribute with a certain value

Tags: powershell

Here is some sample xml:

```
<Transaction>
<Tender>
    <TenderIdentifierSourceCode LanguageCode="eng" CodeContent="06"/>
</Tender>
```

I want to iterate through a directory and move all the xml files that contain the attribute CodeContent where the value is '06':

Tender/TenderIdentifierSourceCode/@CodeContent = '06'

So far, I have this which generates a file list (and just checks to see if the node exists) - But this doesn't work. And I want to check the VALUE of the attribute CodeContent rather than element existance:

```
$Path = "C:\Users\Bex\Documents\Client Projects\QA Refresh\Useful Powershell Scripts"
$PathArray = @()
$Results = "D:\MatchingStringResults.txt"

Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*.xml" -Recurse | 
   Where-Object { $_.Attributes -ne "Directory"} | 
ForEach-Object { $NodeExists = $xml.Transaction.Tender.TenderIdentifierSourceCode
  if($NodeExists){ $PathArray += $_.FullName
  }
  }
Write-Host "Contents of ArrayPath:" $PathArray | ForEach-Object {$_}
read-host "Script Complete - Press ENTER to exit"
$PathArray | % {$_} | Out-File $Results
```

Comment: You have to define your `$xml` variable before you can get its properties. You are missing a step within your `foreach-object` to take the file coming down the pipeline and convert it to an xml object. Only after that would you be able to get at its properties with `$xml.Transaction.Tender.TenderIdentifierSourceCode`.

Watch your output too: the second term in your pipeline doesn't do anything and you need Out-File -Append, or you will overwrite the file with each single output line. `Try: $PathArray | % {Out-File -InputObject $_ -FilePath $Results -Append`

Comment: `Select-Xml -Path *.xml -XPath "(/Transaction/Tender/TenderIdentifierSourceCode/@CodeContent[.='06'])[1]" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path`

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. However, could you please show me how the code above fits into my example (I have never used powershell before and I found the above script online).

Comment: I have got this to work, but again, I want to search for the specific \xml attribute, as the CodeContent attribute is present within multiple nodes:

Answer (score 0):

SO this works. It finds the files with the string and moves to a new directory. However, as in the answer provided by PetSerAl, I want to check the specific xml path as the CodeContent attribute is present in multiple elements.

```
$Path = "C:\Users\Bex\Documents\Client Projects\QA Refresh\Useful Powershell    Scripts\Apple Pay Transactions"
$Text = 'CodeContent="06"'
$PathArray = @()
$Results = "D:\MatchingStringResults.txt"
$Destination = "C:\Users\Bex\Documents\Client Projects\QA Refresh\Useful     Powershell Scripts\FileList"

# This code snippet gets all the files in $Path that end in ".xml" and any subdirectories.
Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*.xml" -Recurse | 
   Where-Object { $_.Attributes -ne "Directory"} | 
      ForEach-Object { 
         If (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $Text) {
            $PathArray += $_.FullName
            Move-Item -path $_.FullName -destination $Destination
         }
      }
```